# Hamburger button doesn't close after initial click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Navbar Component

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { logout } from '../../redux/actions/auth';
import './Navbar.styles.css';
import ham from './assets/ham.svg';
import exit from './assets/exit.svg';

export const Navbar = ({ auth: { isAuthenticated, loading }, logout }) => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const authLinks = (
    <div className='buttons'>
      <Link to='/'>
        <button onClick={logout} className='button'>
          Logout
        </button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );

  const guestLinks = (
    <div className='buttons'>
      <Link to='/register'>
        <button className='button'>Register</button>
      </Link>
      <Link to='login'>
        <button className='button'>Login</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
  console.log(isMenuOpen);
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <header>
        <h2>
          <Link to='/' className='logo' alt='Escapebe logo'>
            <i className='fas fa-microphone'></i> Escapebe
          </Link>
        </h2>
        <nav>
          <Link to='#' className='hide-desktop'>
            <img
              src={ham}
              alt='toggle menu'
              className='menu'
              onClick={() => setIsMenuOpen({ isMenuOpen: !isMenuOpen })}
            />
          </Link>
          <ul
            className={
              isMenuOpen
                ? 'hide-desktop show-mobile'
                : 'show-desktop hide-mobile'
            }
          >
            <li className='exit-btn hide-desktop'>
              <img
                src={exit}
                onClick={() =>
                  setIsMenuOpen({
                    isMenuOpen: !isMenuOpen
                  })
                }
              />
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/'>News</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/'>Groups</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/'>About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/'>FAQ</Link>
            </li>
            {!loading && (
              <Fragment>{isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}</Fragment>
            )}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

Navbar.propTypes = {
  logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(Navbar);
```

HeroSection.styles.css

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
  color: #d1d0d0;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  width: calc(100% - 1em);
  display: block;
  color: #d1d0d0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 3% auto 7%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.triangle {
  margin: 2em auto 2em 45%;
  width: 70%;
}

h1,
.subhead {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.subhead {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .triangle {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .button {
    width: 35%;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .subhead {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 12%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .button {
    width: 35%;
  }

  .container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto 13% auto;
  }

  .hide-desktop {
    display: none;
  }

  .show-desktop {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 13% auto;
  }

  nav ul {
    position: inherit;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  nav ul li {
    float: left;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    background-color: inherit;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 1em 2em;
  }

  nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

Navbar.styles.css

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 130px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hide-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.show-mobile {
  display: initial;
}

.menu {
  width: 25px;
  margin-top: 115%;
}

nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  width: 60%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
  background: rgb(36, 41, 44);
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 7;
  padding-top: 3em;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  background-color: rgb(52, 59, 63);
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(65, 73, 78);
}

.exit-btn {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 1.4em;
}

.exit-btn img {
  width: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and(min-width: 650px) {
  .triangle {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

My hamburger menu isn't working. It works on the initial click but won't close afterwards. If I switch them around, then I can close the menu but not open it. I'm almost 100% sure that it doesn't have to do with the state. I think it may have something to do with my styling. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setIsMenuOpen({ isMenuOpen: !isMenuOpen })
```

This is wrong, It should be

```
setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)
```

I think this should fix.